# CLI method to replace white space from regex capture group

Tags: regex, macos, sed, command-line-interface

I have some markdown files where the URLs have spaces in them. I want to replace the whitespace in the URL with a hyphen. I am not sure if this is even possible with `sed`.

For example:

`[the name of the link](www.example.com/a badly named thing)`

should become

`[the name of the link[(www.example.com/a-badly-named-thing)`

I know that I can capture the bad url with the expression below, but how can I then do something with it?

`s/[.*](/[/1/])/<do something to group 1>/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed -e ':a' -e 's/\(\[[^][]*]([^()[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^()]*)\)/\1-\2/' -e 'ta' file > newfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Jg1vOd).

*Details*:

- `:a` - sets a label
- `\(\[[^][]*]([^()[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^()]*)\)` - a POSIX BRE pattern matching

  - `\(\[[^][]*]([^()[:space:]]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1`):

    - `\[[^][]*]` - a `[`, then zero or more chars other than `]` and `[` and then a `]`
    - `(` - a `(` char
    - `[^()[:space:]]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`, `)` and whitespace
  - `[[:space:]]\{1,\}` - one or more whitespace chars
  - `\([^()]*)\)` - Group 2 (`\2`):

    - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
    - `)` - a `)` char
- The `\1-\2` replacement replaces the match with Group 1 value + `-` + Group 2 value
- `ta` means that if there was a successful substitution, the engine jumps back to the label location.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/\(([^)]*) /(\1-/;ta' input_file
[the name of the link](www.example.com/a-badly-named-thing)
```

Comment: You'll need to check for the close parenthesis, otherwise you can't handle input like `[the name of the link](www.example.com/a badly named thing) plus some other stuff`

Answer (score 1):

Perl, but it's pretty gross:

```bash
perl -pe 's{ \[.+?\] \( \K [^)]+ }{ $url = $&; $url =~ tr/ /-/; $url }xeg'
```

That matches the link name in brackets then the opening parenthesis of the url part and the forgets about that stuff, and then matches a sequence of non-close-parentheses. That matched text is then replaced by the results of a sub-script that changes spaces into hyphens